# Running Python script from c# doesn't work

Tags: c#, python-3.11

I am trying to invoke the following `.py` script: (python version installed: 3.11.4)

```
TaskName= input("Kindly Enter which task should be executed, for Eg: A1,B1,C1 : ")
print(TaskName)
```

from the below simple C# code:

```
string path = @"C:\Program Files\Python311\python.exe";
                string input = @"C:\app\new_7.py";

                ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();                    
                startInfo.FileName = path;
                startInfo.Arguments = "\"" + input + "\"";
                startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;                    
                startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
                {
                    string line = exeProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                    exeProcess.WaitForExit();
                    if (exeProcess.ExitCode == 0) MessageBox.Show("External program is executed successfully.");
                    else MessageBox.Show("External program execution was not successful.");
                    line = string.IsNullOrEmpty(line) ? line : line.TrimEnd(new char[] { '\r', '\n' });

                    MessageBox.Show(line);
                }
```

But, it doesn't show-up the prompt what i see when i run the script by double clicking the `.py` (screenshot below). When debugged, i see this code: `using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))` passes without showing the prompt and gets stuck at next line: `string line = exeProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();`

[image]

Can anyone give some hint on where i am going wrong?
I don't want new window that's why : `startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;`.
If i set it to `False`: it flashes the prompt and goes immediately.

I have seen the similar issue asked in this: [Run Python script in c# does nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621555/run-python-script-in-c-sharp-does-nothing)

But the solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: You can't both redirect the output and not redirect the output - do you want your C# app to consume output or do you want the console user to?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I want my C# app to consume the output and take action further.

Comment: Alright, then [avoid StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160187/standardoutput-readtoend-hangs)

Comment: okay, thanks very much for the link.
now i understood what you were asking actually.
What i basically want is to show the prompt from my .py script to the user (meaning redirect output for the user) 
and then to get the input given by user to my C# app (redirect to my c# app).
 
So, with the solution given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/7608823/5658446, i could get the output to my c# app (not getting stuck anymore),
but missed to show the prompt (screenshot above) to the user so that he can enter his input.

Comment: Gotcha! Yeah, the straightforward solution here is to just read standard output line-by-line and then echo it from the UI of your C# app in realtime as you process it :)

Comment: okay, got your hint. will give a try now.

Comment: I have done the solution of reading the standard output line-by-line and then echoing it from the UI of my C# app. But it works only when i don't add this line "startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;". that means a new blank console window still pops up waiting for user input. how to gulp that?